# Android cursor indexout of bounds for unknown reasons

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I have a problem with my cursor which I know the error of, but hav eNO clue how to solve this.
Let me explain the idea im trying to achieve first before diving into code-mode.

I have two tables in SQL lite.

tbl_checkpoints
_id | parent_id | title | is_checked | quantity

tbl_checkpoint_answers
_id | parent_id | answer | note | is_checked

Cursor wise since both have an equal amount of columns, the array would ofcourse be:
0 = _id
1 = parent_id
2 = title/answer
3 = is_checked/note
4 = quantity/is_checked
(before the / is tbl_checkpoints, after is tbl_checkpoint_answers)

A checkpoint can have a quantity. Let's say for example the quantity is 5.
Then a checkpoint requires to be checked 5 times. On a house for example, the checkpoint would be;
"Is brick in perfect condition"
brick 1: yes
brick 2: yes
brick 3: no
brick 4: no
brick 5: yes

These answers belong in the table_checkpoint_answers table. 
One to many relationship.
One checkpoint can have multiple answers.

Code wise, I am using an activity that displays a form, to fill in a checkpoint.
In the form, which resides in a tab layout.

I have  a setup like this in onCreate()

```
_checkPointCursor = _dbHelper.fetchAllCheckPoints(_parentId);

//I know startManagingCursor() is deprecated. I don't know how to use the new version yet.
startManagingCursor(_checkpointCursor); 

_cursor.moveToPosition(_position);
_answerCursor = _dbHelper.fetchFirstCheckPointAnswer(_checkPointCursor.getInt(0)); 
//getInt(0) returns 1 which is what I expect. (debugged)
```

What happens here is I have a cursor that has all checkpoints where parentid is equal to a given number. 1 in this case(tested. Forced it to be 1, which im sure of the query will give results.

The query I use for fetchAllCheckPoints(_parentId); is:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_checkpoints WHERE parent_id = parentId // parentId = 1
```

This gives me 5 results. This is true in the program aswell and it works fine uptil now. 
_checkpointCursor mCount is 5 according to the debugger.

The next query; fetchFirstCheckPointAnswer(); is :

```
    SELECT * FROM tbl_checkpointAnswers WHERE parent_id = parentId ORDER BY _id ASC LIMIT 0,1
   //primary key of the selected _checkPointCursor() which is 1. so parentId = 1. 
   //Things going well so far..
```

After this query has fired (I have checked using 2 kinds of software, I get 1 result. Which is exactly what I want.

The cursor now sais mCount = -1.
Why? why is mCount on _answerCursor -1?
I am sure I get a result from the query.

the program later crashes when I use:

textView.setText(_answerCursor.getString(2));

The stacktrace:

```
10-19 14:10:04.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12997): FATAL EXCEPTION: main10-19 14:10:04.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12997): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.wvds.activities/com.wvds.activities.TabbedCheckPointActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.wvds.activities/com.wvds.activities.CheckPointFormActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 110-19 14:10:04.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12997):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3128)10-19 14:10:04.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12997):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3143)10-19 14:10:04.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12997):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2684)10-19 14:10:04.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12997):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)10-19 14:10:04.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12997):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)10-19 14:10:04.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12997):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)10-19 14:10:04.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12997):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)10-19 14:10:04.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12997):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)10-19 14:10:04.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12997):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)10-19 14:10:04.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12997):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)10-19 14:10:04.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12997):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)10-19 14:10:04.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12997):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)10-19 14:10:04.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12997):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)10-19 14:10:04.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12997): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.wvds.activities/com.wvds.activities.CheckPointFormActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 110-19 14:10:04.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12997):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3128)10-19 14:10:04.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12997):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:170)10-19 14:10:04.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12997):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.dispatchResume(LocalActivityManager.java:518)10-19 14:10:04.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12997):     at android.app.ActivityGroup.onResume(ActivityGroup.java:58)10-19 14:10:04.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12997):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1149)10-19 14:10:04.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12997):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3823)10-19 14:10:04.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12997):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3118)10-19 14:10:04.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12997):     ... 12 more10-19 14:10:04.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12997): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 110-19 14:10:04.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12997):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)10-19 14:10:04.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12997):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)10-19 14:10:04.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12997):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)10-19 14:10:04.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12997):     at com.wvds.activities.CheckPointFormActivity.loadView(CheckPointFormActivity.java:289)10-19 14:10:04.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12997):     at com.wvds.activities.CheckPointFormActivity.onResume(CheckPointFormActivity.java:126)10-19 14:10:04.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12997):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1149)10-19 14:10:04.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12997):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3823)10-19 14:10:04.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12997):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3118)10-19 14:10:04.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12997):     ... 18 more
```

I hope someone will be able to help me resolve this issue. I look forward to reading your answers/help.

Thanks in advance.

Btw, In case I have typos, in the actual code there are no typos. Not that prevent it from running. 
Due to the situation im in. I cant use internet on my programming pc. So I use an internet pc to write this.

Comment: Didnt check. But the error is solved. I overlooked something very srupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before fatch data you add **cursor.movetofirst();**

Comment: I cant believe it was so simple. I completely overlooked it. Because i tought it was unnescesary. Since it only has one result. Thanks alot.

Comment: Can u explain where exatly a cursor starts. Even whe  it has only one result

Comment: That explains alot. Thanks alot. This was becoming a headache. It works as expected now